# Issue with Circle class and printing vector of class members

Tags: c++

I am having a couple issues with my code.

I am able to sort the vector of **radii** and print them but it is rounding the numbers and cutting off the decimal, I am unsure how to fix it.

Another issue that I have is trying to display the area for each of the radii next to it, I am unable to call the class function 'area' correctly to display the area next to the corresponding radius.

I apologize, I am very new to C++ and I have tried to explain my issue to the best of my ability.

I know my code is a little rudimentary so any pointers would also be appreciated. Also any help with printing the vector and getting the area to display would be appreciated as well. Thanks.

This is the class section:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Circle {

private:

    double radius;  // Radius of circle

public:

    // Default constructor
    Circle() {
        radius = 0.0;
    }
    // Set the radius of the circle
    void setRadius(double r) {
        radius = r;
    }
    // Get the radius of the circle
    double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    // Calculate the area of the circle using current radius
    double area() {
        return(3.1416 * radius * radius);
    }
};

void printVector(vector<int>);
void bubbleSort(vector<int> &);
```

This is main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
cout << "Sorted Vector of Circles" << endl;
cout << "------------------------" << endl;
const int SIZE = 10;
Circle circle;
vector<int> circles;

Circle c1;
c1.setRadius(2.5);
circles.push_back(c1.getRadius());

Circle c2;
c2.setRadius(3.5);
circles.push_back(c2.getRadius());

Circle c3;
c3.setRadius(1.0);
circles.push_back(c3.getRadius());

Circle c4;
c4.setRadius(5.5);
circles.push_back(c4.getRadius());

Circle c5;
c5.setRadius(4.8);
circles.push_back(c5.getRadius());

Circle c6;
c6.setRadius(6.0);
circles.push_back(c6.getRadius());

Circle c7;
c7.setRadius(2.75);
circles.push_back(c7.getRadius());

Circle c8;
c8.setRadius(10);
circles.push_back(c8.getRadius());

Circle c9;
c9.setRadius(0.5);
circles.push_back(c9.getRadius());

Circle c10;
c10.setRadius(9.5);
circles.push_back(c10.getRadius());

bubbleSort(circles);
printVector(circles);

return 0;
}
```

Sort Function:

```
void bubbleSort(vector<int> &radii){
int temp;
bool swap;
do {
    swap = false;
    for(int count = 0;count < radii.size()-1; count++){
        if (radii[count] > radii[count+1]) {
            temp = radii[count];
            radii[count] = radii[count + 1.];
            radii[count+1] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
} while (swap);


}
```

Print function:

```
void printVector(vector<int> radii) {
cout << "Radius" << endl;
cout << "" << endl;
for (int count = 0; count < radii.size(); count++) {
    cout << setw(2) << radii[count] << setprecision(2) << " " << 
radii[count.area()] << " "; // main issue is with this section of code
cout << endl;
}   

}
```

Comment: @JacobSeleznev Better than `count.demonay()`.

Comment: As I said, I am new. I apologize. I do not know how to do it and have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: I think you're expected to sort a vector of circles, `std::vector<Circle>`, by radius and then print their areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::vector<double>` instead of `std::vector<int>`

There is nothing called `count.area()`. `count` is an `integer` variable not a `Circle`

if you want to print the area, you have to pass another vector which is the area vector (you should create one first) to the print function.

Comment: From what I'm reading between the lines in the code `std::vector<Circle>`, with support from a comparator or two, is what OP needs.

Comment: Okay Thank you. I switched them and it seems to be partially working. It displays some of the decimals such as 0.5 and 9.5 but rounds 4.8 to 5 and 2.75 to 3. Is there something wrong with the sorting function that is rounding or is it the printing function?

Comment: @rcwade93 If you have an issue with sorting you should ask a separate question.

Comment: @rcwade93 it is the printing function  "setprecision(2)"

Comment: @user4581301 Yes for sure... but I just tried to answer as the question is.

Comment: I know my code isn't all that great and I appreciate the feedback. I have got it to work with your help and I appreciate it. Thank you all again. I will mess around with making it a vector<Circle> to make it better but I got the printing issue and the decimal issue fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: @rcwade93 You are welcome and please do not hesitate to ask a separate question on any problem you face while it is not googleable and clear enough.